# cast string to location

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

When I export a control's location to string, using the standard Control.Location.ToString method, I get the following:

```
{X=163,Y=196}
```

How can I turn this string back to location? Is there any out-of-the box function, or do I need to parse this string and do it myself?

Update:
I would like to serialize a few objects on the screen to XML to save progress and read it back later.

Comment: Where did that string come from?  It cant be "cast" but perhaps something can be done upstream to convert it easily

Comment: @Plutonix I would assume he did it from the `Control's.Location` property. He of course would of had to output it this way though.

Comment: Yesh, I was more interested whether it is something s/he generated or if it is something from elsewhere that they have no control over or have to use that format for something else to consume @Zaggler

Comment: @Plutonix makes sense and a good question to ask.

Comment: I would avoid turning it into a string in the first place if you can avoid it, e.g. if your storing it within your program's memory, keep it as a `Point`. If you really have to turn it into a string, e.g. if you're serializing it to disk to restore it the next time the program starts, you'll have to parse it yourself.

Comment: Updated the question. Indeed, I used the Location.ToString function.

Comment: What exactly are you doing?  There is a way to do that easily, but if we knew what you were playing at, maybe you dont need to do anything at all.

Comment: Added answer to the question.

Comment: If you are serializing, the serializer can, will and should take a `Point` save it and then convert back.  *You* ought not have to do anything.  When more than one person comments, you need to ping them with `@` + `username` as in the 2nd and 3rd comments,  if you want anyone to know you responded

Comment: Since you can vote, please take a second to do so (click the up arrow).  Voting helps other people find good posts and you can do so on *any* Q or A you find helpful or informative you in some way.  The very brief [tour] explains how it all works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are serializing, then the serializer ought to handle the conversion from `Point` to string and back.  If you examine the serializer output, it should look like this: `727, 97`.

This form is `InvariantString` and NET provides the means to convert these without having to parse the text:

```
Dim pt = Button10.Location

Dim cvtr = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Point))
' convert Pt to invariant string
Dim strPT = cvtr.ConvertToInvariantString(pt)
Console.WriteLine(strPT)

' try to convert back
Dim pt2 = DirectCast(cvtr.ConvertFromInvariantString(strPT), Point)

If pt.Equals(pt2) Then
    Console.Beep()
End If
```

Output:

> 727, 97
>   *(Beep)*

But again, a serializer should convert for you.

---

If you are doing lots of this, a generic version is handy:

```
Private Function CvtToInvariantString(Of T)(item As T) As String
    Dim cvtr = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(T))

    Return cvtr.ConvertToInvariantString(item)
End Function

Private Function CvtFromInvariantString(Of T)(str As String) As T
    Dim cvtr = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(T))

    Return DirectCast(cvtr.ConvertFromInvariantString(str), T)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim strPT = CvtToInvariantString(pt)

Dim pt2 = CvtFromInvariantString(Of Point)(strPT)
```

Comment: Indeed, I was overthinking, the serializer exported the point property as is, thank you :)